# How to cancel keypress action in VB?

Tags: vb.net

This my code for validating empty fields. The purpose of the click is to save the details entered by the person. But the problem is the code to cancel the keypress when the user did not meet the conditions.
The SAVE button should not take me to the file location but instead ask me to re enter details to validate. Can someone help me?

```vb
If creditcard = "" Or name = "" Or streetname = "" Or town = "" Or postcode = "" Or housenumber = "" Then
    cmdPrintReceipt.Enabled = False
    MsgBox("Please leave no blank fields", vbCritical)
Else
    savefiledialogPersonalDetails.ShowDialog()

    Dim location As String
    location = savefiledialogPersonalDetails.FileName

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(location & ".txt", "" & lblReceipt.Text, True)

    cmdPrintReceipt.Enabled = True

    lblReceipt.Text = lblReceipt.Text & " CUSTOMER  " & name & vbCr
    lblReceipt.Text = lblReceipt.Text & " THANK YOU " & name & "YOUR PURCHASE, HOPE TO SEE YOU SOON!!! " & vbCr
End If
```

Comment: You've tagged this with *four* different languages. Please pick one.

Comment: So you mean that it is going to the `Else` condition when you expect it to run the `If` block instead? Have you tried examining the values with a variable to see which one is non-blank? Or, did you mean that you want to add another condition, other than non-blank, that is invalid?

Comment: "So you mean that it is going to the Else condition when you expect it to run the If block instead?" --- this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Firstly, why are you asking about key presses and then talking about a button click? Which is is? Secondly, if the `Else` block is being executed when you expect the `If` block to be executed then obviously the expression in your `If` statement is not evaluating the way you expect so you need to work out why. You do that by debugging and you should have done that before posting here. If you don't know how to debug, using breakpoints and the various tools the IDE provides then stop what you're doing and learn now.

Comment: Also, use `OrElse` rather than `Or`. The same goes for `AndAlso` over `And`.